# Route53 / Lightsail: www subdomain does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I've registered my domain on Route53, deleted the default hosted zone, and set the name servers to the ones provided by Lightsail. I've also set up a hosted zone in Lightsail with two subdomains: @ and www. Both are A records that point to the static IP of my Lightsail instance.

The top-level domain works fine, but the www is giving an "IP address not found" error on my browser. What might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it just takes a while for the DNS to update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.whatsmydns.net/ to check if DNS is updated.

Comment: This answer doesn't give a definite solution. It would be better to move it into comments.